# Just store any data from an object to a table, regardless of what structure it has?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm downloading data from an API, it's badly documented, and I want to store what ever comes out of it into a database, just adding new columns whenever  newly labeled data comes up.

If an object looks like this:

```
{ location:
          position: { 
              latitude: 59.34534777, 
              longitude: 18.27299453 },
          },
       listPrice: 6700000,
       livingArea: 129,
},
```

I would like it to create a table that looks somthing like this:

```
location.position.longitude | location.position.latitude | listPrice | livingArea
59.34534777                 | 18.27299453                | 6700000   | 129
```

Does this have a name? And is there some ORM/library/database that would make this simple for me? Currently i'm using sqlite but that is not a requirement.

Comment: I might recommend just storing the JSON directly, as text.  SQLite does not have a formal JSON type.

Comment: Interesting, though, I want to be able to search it later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document db would work very well for this. MongoDb is a safe choice.